# How to inspect return type of Callable

Tags: python, reflection, python-typing, typing, callable

Let's say I have something like the following:

```py
import inspect
from collections.abc import Callable  # Using Python 3.10+
from typing import get_type_hints

def foo(arg: Callable[..., int]) -> None:
    pass

type_hints = get_type_hints(foo)["arg"]
annotation = inspect.signature(foo).parameters["arg"].annotation
# How can one get the return type `int` from either of these?
```

I can figure out how to get to the `Callable` type hint.  From there, how can one inspect the return type of the `Callable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid access to dunder attributes, which in general is unsafe and can break between version releases, you should use [a method provided by `typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args):

```
type_hint = get_type_hints(foo)["arg"]
arg_types, return_type = get_args(type_hint)
```

This works for any `Callable`. `arg_types` is `Ellipsis` (`...`) or a `list` of args (also may be a `typing.ParamSpec` or `typing.Concatenate`, if you use them), return_type is whatever occupies 2nd place.

Answer (score 2):

```
annotation.__args__

or

type_hints.__args__

(Ellipsis, <class 'int'>)
```